# Function to download file from remote url to server with ability to pause/resume the download

Tags: php, download

I used `file_put_contents` to download videos to server, but I want to know if I can pause/resume or stop the download (when I enter to video downloading page the download starts, and when I stop the page charging the download doesn't stop, it continues at the background)
Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Realized I should post as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with client to server side programming, php is server side so when you run the page there will be no output to the client (browser) until the php code is done running AKA done downloading. Thus PHP CANNOT be paused by the client, You may be able to use php's  exec() to run another program asynchronously. Node.JS supports asynchronous things and the client can modify server activity via sockets. PHP simply does not work well with client-server side communication